# RxJS - Future insertion is not observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a single HTML element :

```
 <ul id="animals"></ul>
```

And this code which observe an array and append its element as HTML elements :

```
  const zooAnimals = ['anteater', 'bear', 'cheetah', 'donkey'];

  const observable = Rx.Observable.from(zooAnimals);

  const subscriber = observable

    .subscribe(
      onNext,
      function onError(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
      },
      function onCompleted() {
        console.log('no more animals!');
      }
    );

  function onNext(animal) {
    const list = document.querySelector('#animals');
    console.log('list', list)
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = animal;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }
```

So now the `#animals` element is filled with 4 `ULs`.

But Now I want to add another element via `setTimeout`

So I add :

```
setTimeout(function (){
  zooAnimals.push('dddddd');
},4000);
```

But nothing happens.

**Question**

What am I missing here and how can I mek this code work if some other soure appends items to the array.

plunker :

https://plnkr.co/edit/xzyjCOR8lKl3tc70kzC9?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how Observables work, in RxJS everything is a stream and to emit new data you need to use the RxJS-api - there are many ways to achieve this for your issue, one of those would be to use a `Subject` - which is basically a combination of `Observer` and `Observable`, meaning that you can emit data on it and at the same time subscribe to it:

```
  const zooAnimals = ['anteater', 'bear', 'cheetah', 'donkey'];
  const subject = new Rx.Subject();

  const subscriber = subject
    .subscribe(
      onNext,
      function onError(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
      },
      function onCompleted() {
        console.log('no more animals!');
      }
    );

  function onNext(animal) {
    const list = document.querySelector('#animals');
    console.log('list', list)
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = animal;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }

  zooAnimals.forEach(animal => subject.onNext(animal));
  setTimeout(() => subject.onNext("giraffe"), 100);
```

I've updated your plunker as well:
https://plnkr.co/edit/bx9NtRT0n5HuZQSCcvkH?p=preview

---

As a sidenote: If you are now starting to get into RxJS I would suggest you to use [RxJS**5**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs), which is the latest version of the library.

Comment: Can you please have a look here ? Didn't get a satisfying  answer there http://stackoverflow.com/q/43419163/859154